# MacBook Pro icons damaged after Sierra Update

Tags: mac, macos, icon

[image]

Some icons in Launchpad are damaged since I've updated to macOS Sierra, like DVD Player, Mail, Image Capture, Contacts. How can I fix this?

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this and any other errors with a simple (yeah, riggghhhttt....) reinstall!